# Rails Elastics Search Result content URL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, routes

I was just trying out the Elastic Search in my Rails app replacing the existing search function. Everything worked nicely but I am getting `http://localhost:3000/contents/video/%23%3CElasticsearch::Model::Response::Result:0x007fe24e118f40%3E` url.

in content.rb

```
def to_param
        "#{id}/#{title.parameterize}.html"
        #"#{id}-#{title.downcase.slice(0..30).gsub(/[^a-z0-9]+/i, '-')}.html"
    end
```

and in search action

```
  def search 
    if params[:q].nil?
      @indexs = []
    else
      @indexs = Content.search params[:q]
    end
```

and in views

```
<% @indexs.each do |f|%>
<%= link_to((truncate f.title, length: 60), {:controller => "contents", :action => "weblinks", :id => f.to_param}, target: "_blank") %>
<% end %>
```

It works fine for the default listing page, but its URL generating error in search result page. Please help,and also how to replace the `{:controller => "contents", :action => "weblinks", :id => f.to_param}` with weblinks_path(:format) routes

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use `elasticsearch` gem, if so you should use records to get ActiveRecord models `@indexs.records`

Comment: Could you please make it more clear. I couldn't understand you.